# Hangouts auto-adjusting volume microphone

Tags: microphone, google-hangouts

I am using Linux Mint 17.3 and Chromium. I use hangouts but the volume keeps adjusting on its own. I disabled the feature in Skype. How do I do disable this useless feature in hangouts? I installed google talk plugin. Can anybody tell me the location of the configuration file of the google talk plugin? And what options need to be set